# Recover overwritten partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I need some help recover files from a partially overwritten partition.

I will start with what happened. I was trying to make a image out of my hard drive using `dd`, but I found somewhere online that using `pv` would tell me the best *bs* count to make the copy, what it didn't say was that it would make the copy.

I ran the following command:

```
pv < /dev/sda > /dev/sdc
```

When I realized what was going on I stopped it, but it had already written around 1GB. I would like to recover the files that were not written over, I suspect those that were are long gone.

If someone knows a way I would be thankful.

Comment: Have a search for Testdisk and a manual/howto for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 100% satisfactory solution to your problem right now, only workarounds. and the one resource that is going to help you now is [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). Furthermore, there is really only one thing I can advise you now: stop writing to the disk, preferably take a clone and work from the clone.

**Why?** Well if someone comes up with a better idea then `testdisk`
, you can start the process over again with a fresh clone!

For the future:

1. Remember that `dd` is the abbreviation of **D**isk **D**estroyer.
2. Read the [following Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc): You're *definitely* user type 4.